# Add Annotations in plotly choropleth map box

Tags: python, plotly, maps

I have a problem adding an annotations in my map. I Would like to add it at the same page below state and color. I don't know how can I use my coordinates instead adding a new one like my code.

I would like to use something like `locations="state"` as my first fig

[image]

[image]

My parcial example geojson

```
[{'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'nombre': 'Tucumán'},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[[-66.20361328125, -26.62781822639305],
     [-66.0498046875, -26.64745870265937],
     [-65.830078125, -26.725986812271756],
     [-65.89599609375, -26.92206991673281],
     [-66.181640625, -27.274161117374668],
     [-65.6103515625, -27.994401411046148],
     [-65.4345703125, -27.89734922968425],
     [-65.0390625, -27.89734922968425],
     [-64.4677734375, -26.29341500426577],
     [-65.36865234375, -26.07652055985696],
     [-65.85205078125, -26.31311263768267],
     [-66.11572265625, -26.2145910237943],
     [-66.20361328125, -26.62781822639305]]]}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'nombre': 'Santiago del Estero'},
```

This is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import json
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Cargar el archivo GeoJSON con los límites de las provincias de Argentina
with open("ProvinciasArgentina.geojson", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    geojson_data = json.load(file)

data = {
    "state": ["Santa Fe", "Buenos Aires"],  # Agrega más states según tus datos
    "color": [1, 2,],
    "prices": ["$1200", "$300"],  # Información adicional para cada state
    "lat_for_text": [-34.61, -31.63],
    "long_for_text": [-58.38,  -60.70]

}

# Crear el gráfico de choropleth
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    data,
    geojson=geojson_data,
    locations="state",
    featureidkey="properties.nombre",  # Asegúrate de que coincida con la clave en tu GeoJSON
    color="color",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",  # Puedes ajustar el estilo de Mapbox según tus preferencias
    center={"lat": -35, "lon": -65},
    zoom=4,
    title="Mapa de Provincias de Argentina",
        opacity=0.3  # Ajusta la transparencia aquí (0 es completamente transparente, 1 es completamente opaco)

)

texttrace = go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=data['lat_for_text'],
        lon=data['long_for_text'],
        text=data['prices'],
        mode="text",
        name="Price",
        hoverinfo='text'

    )

fig.add_trace(texttrace)

# Mostrar el gráfico
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

adding hover_data into mapbox:

```
# Crear el gráfico de choropleth
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    data,
    geojson=geojson_data,
    locations="state",
    featureidkey="properties.nombre",  # Asegúrate de que coincida con la clave en tu GeoJSON
    color="color",
    hover_data="prices",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",  # Puedes ajustar el estilo de Mapbox según tus preferencias
    center={"lat": -35, "lon": -65},
    zoom=4,
    title="Mapa de Provincias de Argentina",
        opacity=0.3  # Ajusta la transparencia aquí (0 es completamente transparente, 1 es completamente opaco)

)
```